# JMS QPID Queue vs Topic

Tags: spring, queue, jms, qpid

I'm confused when it comes to JMS Queue/Topic.  What I want is messages should go to every subscriber and I want subscribers to receive messages from inactive time when they become active.  However, I don't have control over whether or not subscribers have durable subscription. Is there a way to set up a persistent Queue, and set it up so that every subscriber will receive same message?  And how to set this up using spring config

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a question where the design of your system affects the outcome.

You could use UI tooling to create durable subscriptions for the clients that need to but that is cumbersome and error prone.  You could use something like camel or other configuration on the target broker to fanout messages from an incoming Queue to outgoing Queues that map to the consumer subscriptions.

It all depends mostly on the requirements and your overall design so a real answer is beyond the scope of a SO answer without you doing some more legwork to narrow the scope a bit.  JMS itself does not define any answer for this so it will come down a bit to the broker you've chosen and possibly other third party tooling that you might pick to do what you need.